# Why is a view object indexable in the context of the Python sorted() function?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, indexing

step 1: create a dictionary

```
dict1 = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "zero": 0}
```

step 2: reveal dict1's contents

```
dict1 
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'zero': 0}
```

step 3: create a view object using .items()

```
vwobj = dict1.items()
```

step 4: reveal the object's contents (a list of tuples)

```
vwobj
dict_items([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('zero', 0)])
```

step 5: 'sort' (a dictionary is not sortable) the dictionary based on values

```
dict2 = sorted(vwobj, key=lambda p0: p0[1])
```

step 6: reveal dict2's contents (0, 1, 2 'sorted')

```
dict2
[('zero', 0), ('one', 1), ('two', 2)]
```

step 7: create a lambda function (outside the sorted() function)

```
def key(p0):
    return p0[1]
```

step 8: and use the view object as its argument

```
key(vwobj)
TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing
```

step 9: and a TypeError results. Question ... why is it possible to index the view object in the context of the sorted() function only (what am I missing) ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not indexing the view object in the context of the sorted function.  In `dict2 = sorted(vwobj, key=lambda p0: p0[1])`, the `key` function is applied to the *elements* of `vwobj`, not to `vwobj` itself.  So the `sorted()` function is evaluating `('one', 1)[1]`, etc., which works, while `key(vwobj)` tries to evaluate `vwobj[1]`, which doesn't work.